# Is there a way to use Netflix on PS3 without PSN?

Tags: psn, netflix

When I initially heard of the PSN outage, I thought it would be no big deal for me.  After all, I don't play a lot of multiplayer or online games on that system.  For that matter, it's been awhile since I've played *any* games on the PS3.  Most of the time I'm just using it for... oh... right... Netflix.

Why there is any reason for me to log into PSN to use Netflix is beyond me.  For some reason it's required, but at the same time content will still load in the background even if I don't log in.  I found that out myself on accident today, while trying to cancel the login and get back to the PlayStation menu (a process which in itself is annoyingly painful).

So, is there any way to actually *use* Netflix on the PS3 without having to log in to PSN?  I imagine there might be some means of doing it through rooting the system or other similar hacks.  However, I'd much rather avoid this as it is quite probable that Sony will eventually ban such devices from the network.  (Though I don't often use it for much other than Netflix, I'd still rather not lose it.)  So, I would like an answer that provides the simplest, most "legal" method available if there is one.

Comment: It seems like a permissions issue: even without connecting to PSN (by canceling 3 login attempts), Netflix can confirm that I'm a member and will get my instant queue, recommendations and such, and it will load about 20% of a title while it waits for me to log in, but I can't get farther without a PSN connection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you click cancel when it asks you to log into PSN you will be fine. It usually takes 2 or 3 cancels but I am able to log into netflix just fine. I have heard on some of the older model systems, this will not work but there is a trick. If you clear out your BD-Data folder for some reason or another this seems to take care of it.

Answer (score 6):

I've heard that Netflix on the PS3 will eventually give up trying to connect to PSN if you tell it to retry a few times, but I don't have Netflix on my PS3 so I can't test it.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah it works just keep trying. It worked on the third time for me. I'm watching The Other Guys on my PS3 via Netflix right now.